# Can I track other users on Tor?

Tags: anonymity, security, windows

I'm an admin on a Windows 8.1 computer and I want to know if I can see what another user is doing on Tor. Would I just use Microsoft Family Safety? I know that the government can spy on Tor, but can I see what other users are doing? I am either a parent or manager of a small company. Or both. Either way I need to see what my kids and/or employees are doing.

*Note: I [already asked this on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/933866/is-there-a-way-to-track-tor-browsing-activities), but then I found a site specific to Tor.  Please don't blame me for being redundant.*

Comment: If you think you need this kind of surveillance, maybe your actual problem is not fixable by technical means, but rather by conversation and understanding.

Comment: Parent or company owner, the recommendation is the same: Don't let them install Tor. It's designed specifically to defend against what you're doing.

Comment: Installl a keylogger and or screenlogger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell *that* they use Tor, but not *what they do* on Tor. Not from sniffing the network alone.

If you own the machines they use, you could install software on it that tells you what they do, regardless of Tor. **This is not something I would recommend you do without telling your kids/employees!**

At the end of the day, Tor was designed against you.

Comment: What software would that be?

Comment: I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I'll go block the [torproject.org](http://torproject.org) and delete the application.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can see your user using Tor but you can't figure out what sites they visit.

Comment: Aren't you _not_ supposed to restate what someone just said on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @LeoWilson this was the 1st answer